# Replicate MySQL to Hadoop

Tags: mysql, hadoop, replication

I'm looking for an open source to replicate MySQL to Hadoop, I found two options, but

- Sqoop, Flume: not support realtime UPDATE, DELETE
- Tungsten: closed source and pricing

so what other tools to meet that requirement?

Answer (score 2):

With Best of My Knowledge Kafka can be Useful for your case.

Kafka-mysql-connector is a plugin that allows you to easily replicate MySQL changes to Apache Kafka and from Kafka you can load to HDFS or HIVE

- For a MySQL->Kafka solution based on Kafka Connect, check out the excellent Debezium project.

http://debezium.io/

- For a MySQL->Kafka solution that is a standalone application, check out the excellent Maxwell project, upon which this connector was based.

http://maxwells-daemon.io/

**Hope this Helps**

(**Note:** I have not used this solution but you can give a try)

Comment: Thank you so much, I was thinking about it but time is limited so my temporary solution is Sqoop Job to batch import and overwrite old data with Hive. I will try your solution when have more time.